# Good book about Scapy

Tags: sniffer, professional-education

Is there any good learning resources for Scapy apart from the official documentation? I am looking for a good book about the [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)

Answer (score 4):

"[Security Power Tools](http://www.amazon.ca/Security-Power-Tools-Bryan-Burns/dp/0596009631)" (O'Reilly Media, 2007) has a chapter on Scapy.

"[Python for Unix and Linux System Administration](http://www.amazon.ca/Python-Unix-Linux-System-Administration/dp/0596515820)" (O'Reilly Media, 2008) also has a short section on Scapy

Both of those books are available on Safari Books Online and Amazon.

But, it looks like the various online documentation sources are the best bet:

1. [Scapy Documentation](http://www.dirk-loss.de/scapy-doc/Scapy.pdf) - This is from the authors.
2. [The very unofficial dummies guide to Scapy](https://theitgeekchronicles.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/scapyguide1.pdf)